# MyBatis : Mapping collection of results as a Map

Tags: java, hashmap, set, mapping, mybatis

I've spent several days (and nights) without luck, trying to figure out a way of mapping the results of a query using a Map collection in MyBatis (v.3.3.1) The problem is that MyBatis returns a list/set of Maps instead of an actual Map i.e. the list of rows is mapped to a list of Maps and for each row the column name is used as the key and each column content as the value for the map.

I know that you can use a "ResultHandler" to manipulate the mapping for each returned row but that would imply using a temporary field in the entity and assign back the actual map built by the "ResultHandler" since my entity contains other fields and collections or maybe make two separate queries and separate resultMaps but i don't like it that much.I know there is also as well a `"selectMap()"` method but that neither builds a "true" map of key/value pairs and i can't use it for the same reasons above (i would like to keep using `"selectOne()"` to retrieve at once the entity and all its fields populated).

Finally, i came out with this "workaround" (aka code smell) : Exposing the internal map of a custom HashSet as shown in the following gist :

https://gist.github.com/pnavais/81a83dea3b0fb190fab01b5a5de9b7d1

and mapping the columns to the properties set in the resultMap as follows :

```
<collection property="properties" javaType="org.payball.db.core.collection.MapHackSet" ofType="Map.Entry">
    <id     property="key"   column="PROP_KEY"/>
    <result property="value" column="PROP_VALUE"/>
</collection>
```

Once retrieved from MyBatis i can handle the Set as a map as follows :

```
MapHackSet<String, String> properties = entityFound.getProperties();
properties.get("key");
```

Obviously this is kind of hackish and extremely ugly so I kindly ask for a valid workaround to obtain an actual map from MyBatis.

Comment: What about using a TypeHandler to simply map the whole ResultSet to your map?

Comment: has you try the @MapKey annotation?